# Voxel neighborhood indexing - Detecting "out of bounds" in 26 neighbor access with linear indexing

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix-indexing

Well, I don't know how to describe my problem with a title, I hope the one I got is correct.

I have a matrix (`M`in the example below) that is a 3D image, composed, in this case, by *11x11x11* voxels (I made it logical just for easiness, and size is just an example also).

In my code, I need to reach the 26 neighbors of some voxels, and for that I use some fancy linear indexing found in: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86900-how-to-find-all-neighbours-of-an-element-in-n-dimensional-matrix

The problem is that if the `point` is in the "boundary" of `M` some out of bounds values are tried to be accessed, and that will generate an error.

To solve this problem, a good approach would be to create a boundary around `M` making it +2 size in every dimension, and populate that with zeros, however **I really would like to avoid changing `M`**, as my code is quite more complex that the one in the example.

I cant find any way of doing it, i'm a bit stuck here. Any suggestion?

**EDIT:** @Dan answer works, however I would like to see if there is a possible solution using this linear indexing method.

```
% Example data
M=round(randn(11,11,11))~=0;

% Fancy way of storing 26 neigh indices for good accesing 
s=size(M);
N=length(s);
[c1{1:N}]=ndgrid(1:3);
c2(1:N)={2};
neigh26=sub2ind(s,c1{:}) - sub2ind(s,c2{:});

point=[5 1 6];

% This will work unless the point is in the boundary (like in this example)
neighbours=M(sub2ind(s,point(1),point(2),point(3))+neigh26)
```

Comment: `c2(1:N)={2};`... is that always going to be `{2}` or should is it just `point(1)`?

Comment: @Dan Those 5 lines to create neigh26 are called only once. neigh26 is the difference between a linear index and its 26 neighbours for a given matrix size 's'. Try it with point=[2 2 2]; to test its result. The numerical value is just a coincidence, let me change that...

Comment: Not sure if I got that right, so let me ask you - If `point` is on boundary, you would have lesser than `26` neighbors, and it would be either `17` (for on one edge) or `11` (for on one corner). So what must be the output for such cases? Should it be `17` and `11` or should we pad with zeros around M and make it `26` neighbors too for those cases?

Comment: .. To add to my previous comment, if I could include the voxel itself, it would be `18` (for on one edge) or `12` (for on one corner). So how must the output be reported for such boundary cases?

Comment: @Divakar The ideal thing would be to have a different size(neigh26) in those cases. So if the point is in one boundar, neigh26 (forget the var name) would be a 2x3x3 matrix, in case of an edge 2x2x3 matrix and in the case of a corner 2x2x2.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Don't you mean `2x3x3` for an edge case and `2x2x3` for a corner? Also with such restrictions, if you are working with a number of voxels, the sizes would be different and as such if you are trying to get `neighbors for all voxels` in one go without using loops, you would most certainly have to use cell arrays I think.

Comment: @Divakar There are 3 situations where a point may have less neighbors: Its in the "edge" of 1, 2 or 3 planes. I meant what i wrote there, but I might have used wrong terminology. All this is happening in a huge function inside some functions inside some loops (unavoidable loops), but each time I call neighbors I call it for a single point. Its an iterative algorithm where some matrixes got updated etc.

Comment: @Divakar being more specific, in a ideal situation, neigh26 would be 2x3x3 if its touching the X plane only, 3x2x3 if its in the Y plane and 3x3x2 if its in the Z (extrapolate for 2 plane case). However, this might be too complex to achieve. As long as I know which points are not being accessed, its not a problem if neigh26 is allways 3x3x3 and has 0  in the position that are not going to be used as a neigh.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sorry, had to get off my system. So, how about we pad with NaNs, thus we would have `M_padded` as `13x13x13` and index into `M_padded` instead of `M`. After indexing, the `NaN` elements would indicate "invalid" elements for boundary `point`'s. Would this approach work for you?

Comment: @Divakar I guess it would work, yes! However, dont break your mind,  Dan,s answer works very well for this (the last part, the one of the function for linear indexing)

Comment: @AnderBiguri It's ok, I guess I can handle it :) Well I have a sort of interesting code with `bsxfun` that I think I could run through you.

Comment: @Divakar Well go for it then, its interesting to see that. With bsxfun? YOU? IMPOSSIBLE! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that linear indexing stuff essential? Because it's pretty easy to handle boundary conditions is you use subscript indexing and `min` and `max` like this:

```
p = [5, 1, 6];

neighbourhood = M(max(1,p(1)-1)):min(p(1)+1,end),
                  max(1,p(2)-1)):min(p(2)+1,end),
                  max(1,p(3)-1)):min(p(3)+1,end))

%// Get rid of the point it self (i.e. the center)
neighbours = neighbourhood([1:13, 15:end])
```

This way you can also easily generalize this if you want a broader neighbourhood:

```
p = [5, 1, 6];
n = 2;
neighbourhood = M(max(1,p(1)-n)):min(p(1)+n,end),
                  max(1,p(2)-n)):min(p(2)+n,end),
                  max(1,p(3)-n)):min(p(3)+n,end))

%// Get rid of the point it self (i.e. the center)
mid = ceil(numel(neigbourhood)/2);
neighbours = neighbourhood([1:mid-2, mid+1:end])
```

or if you liked to keep the cube shape then maybe:

```
neighbours = neighbourhood;
neighbours(mid) = NaN;
```

If you want to use this many times in your code it's probably best to refactor it as an m-file function that just returns the indices:

```
function ind = getNeighbours(M,p,n)
    M = zeros(size(M));
    M(max(1,p(1)-n)):min(p(1)+n,end), max(1,p(2)-n)):min(p(2)+n,end), max(1,p(3)-n)):min(p(3)+n,end)) = 1;
    M(p(1), p(2), p(3)) = 0;
    ind = find(M);
end
```

Comment: You have a point here, however let me have this question open for a bit more time. The linear indexing thing is because i have some more complicated fancy indexing around and its WAY more readable accessing the data like that. If I add you lines, I can have some Matlab lines of around 7~10 lines long (if you fit them on screen). I would really like to keep the linear indexes, however, if nobody finds a solution I will accept your answer.

Comment: However, that use of 'end' its fantastic, you shoudl know ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri added anonymous function, hopefully no typos!

Comment: mmmm I get error of "undefined n" if I use you anonymous function.

Comment: @AnderBiguri woops, added `n` as a parameter. I'll also add just a 26 neighbour one too.

Comment: I have been looking at my code more into detail trying to fit your answer in it. Buuut, anonymous functions wont work for me. I reall yneed to play with thisneihgbours quite a bit, so with linear index method saying M1(p+neigh26)=M2(p+neigh26)+1; (obviusly just an example) is too easy. Subscript indexing would make this way more complicated (but would work ofc) but anonymous function wont work here. However I really appreciate the effort you made to give me this answer!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I see. Well as a final attempt, I've added a helper m-file function. You'd use it like `M1(getNeighbours(M1,p,1)) = ...`

Comment: My code is a hell, but that last function did REALLY the job. Amazing anwser and amazing job, as usual. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic theory:** Extend input array to `left-right`, `up-down`, `one more on each sides of the third dimension` with `NaNs`. This would allow us to use a uniform `3x3x3` grid and then later on use those `NaNs` to detect elements that go beyond the boundaries of input array and as such are to be discarded.

**Code**

```
%// Initializations
sz_ext = size(M)+2; %// Get size of padded/extended input 3D array
M_ext = NaN(sz_ext); %// Initialize extended array
M_ext(2:end-1,2:end-1,2:end-1) = M; %// Insert values from M into it

%// Important stuff here : Calculate linear offset indices within one 3D slice
%// then for neighboring 3D slices too
offset2D = bsxfun(@plus,[-1:1]',[-1:1]*sz_ext(1)); %//'
offset3D = bsxfun(@plus,offset2D,permute([-1:1]*sz_ext(1)*sz_ext(2),[1 3 2]));

%// Get linear indices for all points
points_linear_idx = sub2ind(size(M_ext),point(:,1)+1,point(:,2)+1,point(:,3)+1);
%// Linear indices for all neighboring elements for all points; index into M_ext
neigh26 = M_ext(bsxfun(@plus,offset3D,permute(points_linear_idx,[4 3 2 1])))
```

**How to use:** Thus, each slice in the `4th` dimension represent the `27` elements (neighboring plus the element itself) as `3x3x3` array. Hence, `neigh26` would be a `3x3x3xN` array where `N` is the number of points in point array.

**Example:** As an example, let's assume some random values in `M` and `Point` -

```
M=rand(11,11,11);
point = [
    1 1 4;
    1 7 1]
```

On running the earlier code with these inputs, I get something like this -

```
neigh26(:,:,1,1) =
       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN    0.5859    0.4917
       NaN    0.6733    0.6688
neigh26(:,:,2,1) =
       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN    0.0663    0.5544
       NaN    0.3440    0.3664
neigh26(:,:,3,1) =
       NaN       NaN       NaN
       NaN    0.3555    0.1257
       NaN    0.4424    0.9577
neigh26(:,:,1,2) =
   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN
neigh26(:,:,2,2) =
       NaN       NaN       NaN
    0.7708    0.3712    0.2866
    0.7088    0.3743    0.2326
neigh26(:,:,3,2) =
       NaN       NaN       NaN
    0.4938    0.5051    0.9416
    0.1966    0.0213    0.8036
```